# How to fix error 500 installing elgg on WAMP

Tags: wamp, elgg

I am trying to install elgg version 1.12.3 on WAMP, but i keep getting an 'Internal Server error' on Requeriments Step.

I activate "mod_rewrite" on my apache, and check the htaccess file. Still have no idea why dnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 error is a very generic error that does not tell much itself (it's basically "something is very wrong on server side"). You should have more details in Apache error log. It's likely that either something is off with Apache configuration or additional thing is required in .htaccess. Error log should make it clear. You can find it under "Apache" -> "Apache error log" in wampmanager.exe options.